# How do I mock the NestClient DebugInformation in C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nunit, moq

I'd like to Moq the response from the `ElasticClient` to show an error or some information in the `DebugInformation` property.

I have the following:

```
ISearchResponse<person> personResponse = new SearchResponse<person>();
personResponse.ApiCall = new ApiCallDetails
{
    Success = false,
};
personResponse.DebugInformation = "Something happened"; //This is not allowed

_elasticClient.Setup(s =>
    s.Search<person>(
        It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<person>, ISearchRequest>>()))
    .Returns(personResponse);
```

I am unable to assign to DebugInformation as it is readonly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Someone suggested I Moq the Interface of the response instead

So I mocked it Like this

```
Mock<ISearchResponse<person>> mockResponse = new Mock<ISearchResponse<person>>();
mockResponse.Setup(s => s.ApiCall.DebugInformation).Returns("Something");
mockResponse.Setup(s => s.ApiCall.Success).Returns(false);
mockResponse.Setup(s => s.Hits).Returns(new List<IHit<person>>());


_elasticClient.Setup(s =>
    s.Search<person>(
        It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<person>, ISearchRequest>>()))
    .Returns(mockResponse.Object);
```

... and this works!